# HSQLDB invoking stored procedure results in permission error

Tags: stored-procedures, hsqldb

I have a spring based java web application which inserts a huge set of records in a transaction with a HSQLDB dbms backend. In order to reduce the roundtrips for generating primary keys for the records to be inserted I had the idea to create a stored procedure which generates primary keys which will be used as identifiers before doing the insert. So I created a stored procedure with the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_GENERATED_PKS_SEQ_VALUES(
     IN NUMBEROFIDS INTEGER,
     OUT GENERATEDID NUMERIC ARRAY)
     BEGIN ATOMIC
      DECLARE GENID NUMERIC ARRAY;
      DECLARE COUNTER INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
      WHILE COUNTER <= NUMBEROFIDS DO
       SET GENID[COUNTER] = NEXT VALUE FOR GENERATE_PKS_SEQ;
      END WHILE;
      SET GENERATEDID = GENID;
     END;
```

There is a sequence GENERATE_PKS_SEQ which is already in place for generating unique identiiers for records to be inserted. This stored procedure expects a numeric input (NUMBEROFIDS) for defining the number of keys to be generated.

If I execute this statement for CREATING the stored procedure in the HSQLDB database manager (Swing application) everything works fine. That is, there is no error when I execute the statement.

After creating the stored procedure, I try to access it in order to test the output. So basically, I execute the following commnand in the HSQLDB database manager:

```
call GET_GENERATED_PKS_SEQ_VALUES(10);
```

So I just want to create 10 primary key using the mentioned sequence. The result of the statement is the following error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpPbv.png)

I don't know why there is a permission error to execute the stored procedure. I created the stored procedure with the same user account which invoked the procedure with the mentioned parameter. The HSQL DBMS version is hsqldb-2.4.0. Has anybody a clue about my mistake? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the procedure has two parameters, you must call it with two parameters.

For tests, you can use `DECLARE TESTVAR NUMERIC ARRAY` then use `call GET_GENERATED_PKS_SEQ_VALUES(10, TESTVAR)`

In a Java program, the second parameter should be a `?` and it should be retrieved using the `getArray()` method of JDBC `CallableStatement` class.